# Error opening file for writing

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

When I try to install TorBrowser on Windows 7 I get the following error: "Error opening file for writing: C:\xxx\TorBrowser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe"

If I ignore the error all other files install correctly but Tor obviously won't start because the executable wasn't installed. I've re-downloaded the install file etc... and still won't install correctly. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Install it to your desktop folder or similar, it looks like a permissions error.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried installing to multiple folders including the desktop (which is the default directory.)

Comment: You could also right click the installer and run as Administrator

Comment: Simply let the TOR it install/save on the desktop and not change the route of when installing the TOR. As it seems the default file path is the desktop. It worked for me.

Comment: Thank-you @thabroccalidood , I had just ran it as administrator, and was able to install to any destination file.
Good day yall.